# Bootstrap grid dynamically positioning/transforming elements

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is it possible, that instead of transforming all elements to `width: 100%` when you get to the `min-width` for that selected `col-*`, you could move the last element to the new line and update the width of the elements in the original line?

I am using also sass, if that makes it easier.

Is this possible with bootstrap CSS without writing any javascript code?

**From:**

[image]

**To:**

[image]

*Not OK:*

[image]

Now I am having problem when I have items on the left and right side of this content. The width should be static, and now changing size of window messes up the content. Add action should be in new line when Dimensions Names are horizontally.

Plus:
Dimension Name col-lg-2 min width is not big enough.

example: http://jsfiddle.net/mato75/s8tmqvoo/2/

Answer (score 2):

Yes...

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4">Data 1</div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4">Data 2</div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4">Data 3</div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4">Data 4</div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4">Data 5</div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4">Data 6</div>
</div>
```

On medium screens this will have four across.  On small screens this will have three across, and the fourth element (`Data 4` in this example) will display on a second line.

Whatever you end up using depends on how you want the content to display on different screen resolutions.  If you want this to display on mobile as you describe then change `col-sm-4` to `col-xs-4`.

#### [Bootply Demo](http://www.bootply.com/47opG8rUER)

Comment: thx, but how would i edit this, so that when the screen gets wider, instead of 4 elements, I have 5 elements in first line, and if it gets even wider 6, and so on?

Comment: I just edited it.  This is the way to go though if this thing is going to change a lot (sometime 6 across, sometimes 8, etc) then you're going to need to make it more dynamic either by changing display with server side language (like PHP) or using JS.